# How to exit with error from script to Airflow?

Tags: airflow

Say I'm running:

```
t = BashOperator(
    task_id='import',
    bash_command="""python3 script.py '{{ next_execution_date }}' """,
    dag=dag)
```

And for some reason I want the script to exit with error and indicate airflow that he should retry this task.

I tried to use `os._exit(1)` but Airflow mark the task as success.
I know there is:

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
raise AirflowException("error msg")
```

But this is more for functions written in a DAG. My script is independent and sometimes we run it alone regardless of airflow.

Also the script is `Python3` while Airflow is running under Python 2.7
It's seems excessive to install Airflow on `Python3` just for error handling.

Is that any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `|| exit 1` at the end of your Bash command:

```
bash_command="""python3 script.py '{{ next_execution_date }}' || exit 1 """
```

**More information**: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309344